# Hunspell/Aspell data conversion to human-readable inflection list

Tags: aspell, hunspell

Is there an easy way to generate a human-readable inflection list from Hunspell/Aspell dictionary data files?

For example, I'd like to generate the following outputs (for different languages):

...

book, books

book, books, booked, booking

...

go, goes, went, gone, going

...

I looked at the Hunspell/Aspell docs, but couldn't find an API call that would do this.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42566916/1930509

Comment: and: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13725861/1930509

Answer (score 1):

There is a method that the command line one does, but it doesn't output quite in the format you're looking for.  You could also do this manually if you wanted though just by some simple scripting with regex.

The format of for each set of affixes is

```
TYPE TAG REMOVE REPLACE MATCH
```

Such that where `TAG` matches what follows what's behind the `/`in a given word in the `.dic`file, you can do the following (presuming you've already stripped the word of the `/...`):

if($word =~ /$match$/) $word =~ s/$remove$/$replace/;

Notice the `$` there matching the end-of-line/word.  Adjust with `^` if it's a prefix.

There are three caveats:

1. The $match directly from the `.aff` file is in *almost* all cases equivalent to standard regex.  There are minor variations such that if the match is something like `[abc-gh]`, you'd be better to change it to `(a|b|c|-|g|h)` or `[abcgh-]` (hunspell doesn't use hyphen as a metacharacter) otherwise it'll be interpreted as `[abcdefgh]` (standard regex).  For a negated character class, your options are to manually move the `-` to the end of the expression (e.g. `[^a-df]` to `[^adf-]` or to use negative look behinds.
2. If $replace is 0, then you should change it to an empty string.
3. If your result ends with `/...`, you need to reprocess it again because it has a double affix.

Be careful.  By my rough calculations, the dictionary I'm working on could have more than 50 million words being formed (and I wouldn't be surprised if it hits beyond 100 million).