# How to obtain all possible words from given hunspell dictionary?

Tags: c#, spell-checking, hunspell, nhunspell

I would like to parse open office supporting hunspell formatted `aff` and `dic` files.

English `aff` and `dic` files can be downloaded from here for example : http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/english-dictionaries-apache-openoffice

I want to scan each line of the given `.dic` file and generate every possible word of the each line with the provided `.aff` file

How can i do that?

I have installed NHunspell framework but it does not have that feature : https://www.nuget.org/packages/NHunspell/

For example for the english language lets consider

```
make/UAGS
```

make can be `make, made, makes, making` etc

Now i need parser to give me all these combinations. How can i obtain them? Ty very much

So basically i want to scan each line of the dictionary and generate all possible words from the word of that line and i dont know how can i do that

I can also write my own parsers, but it seems to me rules are pretty complex and there are no detailed and easy documentation about this

Here what i want basically. The image explains very clearly

Giving `analyze/ADSG`, `en.dic` and `en.aff` file and obtaining all the following words

```
analyze, analyzes, analyzing, analyzed, reanalyze, reanalyzes, reanalyzing, reanalyzed
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know if that's viable without a third party library, even if you wrote your own parsers there would be a lot of exception.  What do you need all forms of the word for

Comment: so i can have a static list of all words in that particular language and keep associations of words (e.g. makes is composed from make). that is necessary for my application. i mean these applications already has to be obtaining all forms of the given words in dictionary to do particular actions. so i believe there must be a way to do this

Comment: There is a stand way in which most languages convert words,  I.E Future Tense Make -> Present tense -> Making.   Shake -> Shaking,  you can create rules future->present tense end in e drop the e and add ing. This will generally work for most words, but things going from future tense to past however differ a lot of the time.  Make -> Made, Shake -> Shook, Run -> Ran,  Where there may be rules that you can create but there will still be a lot of exceptions.  I think your best bet would be to look for a pre-existing DB of associated words, or to look for a third party library who will handle that

Comment: @johnny5 i really need to solve this problem :( i have updated my question. I am pretty sure what i want is possible. Check the  updated question ty

Comment: I see so all of the rules are already included and mapped with the dictionary this is way easier to understand

Comment: I don't see a function to translate this based on a rule but then again I'm on my phone.  The parser doesn't look too hard to write. Just store a dictionary of string to list of prefix data, match a prefix to the applied regex

Comment: @johnny5 i found the command :) it is wordforms. however i dont know how to call it yet :(  https://github.com/kris7t/hunspell/blob/master/src/tools/wordforms . i need to write output to a file

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Did you find a way to export all the words from the DIC and AFF files? I'm dealing with this problem too.

Comment: maybe related: https://github.com/en-wl/wordlist/tree/master/agid

Answer (score 8):

If you want the entire database you may execute `unmunch`:

```
unmunch dictionary.dic dictionary.aff
```

Note that the current implementation of unmunch in hunspell has a limitation of maximum number of words, affs, and length of generated words. So, unmunch may fail if the target language is beyond the limits of unmunch.

If you want just the list of possible words that can be generated from an entry, you may use `wordforms`:

```
wordforms dictionary.aff dictionary.dic word
```

Answer (score 0):

As Kartal Tabak pointed out, what you are looking for are the command-line tools `wordforms` and `unmunch`, which are distributed with Hunspell. But `wordforms` is for just one stem, and `unmunch` is very buggy. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725861/generate-all-word-forms-using-lucene-hunspell/#66661578) for alternatives.

Furthermore, [it seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889173/nhunspell-how-to-generate-all-recognized-words/#25895341) that Hunspell does not expose this feature as library functions. If you want to use this feature programmatically (as you mentioned C# and NHunspell), then you probably need to spawn these external programs and parse their output.

Answer (score 0):

CSpell's `hunspell-reader` package allows you to get a full word list from a dictionary:

[From their website](https://github.com/streetsidesoftware/hunspell-reader):

> Converting Hunspell to word list
>
> To convert a Hunspell dictionary to a word list, you will need both the `.dic` and `.aff` files. For example en_US comes with two files: `en_US.dic` and `en_US.aff`. This tool assumes they are both in the same directory.
>
> Assuming these files are in the current directory, the following command will write the words to `en_US.txt`.
>
> ```
> hunspell-reader words ./en_US.dic -o en_US.txt
> ```