# NHunspell - How to generate all recognized words?

Tags: nlp, hunspell, nhunspell

Is it possible with NHunspell to generate the list of all recognized/valid words? As far as I remember it was possible with hunspell (unmunch) from the command line.

From current hunspell documentation:

```
munch: dictionary generation from vocabularies (it needs an affix file, too).
unmunch: list all recognized words of a MySpell dictionary 
wordforms: word generation (Hunspell version of unmunch)
```

Comment: Be aware that `unmunch` is outdated and very buggy. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725861/generate-all-word-forms-using-lucene-hunspell/#66661578).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not possible with NHunspell at the moment because it isn't part of the Hunspell library but only the Hunspell command line tool. I've implemented nearly all functions of the Hunspell library in NHunspell, but not all command line tools. If you want it implemented please suggest this feature in the NHunspell forum: 
http://www.crawler-lib.net/boards/forum/5/nhunspell

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I opened a topic in the forum: http://www.crawler-lib.net/boards/topic/14/feature-request-generate-all-recognizedvalid-words

Comment: Wow this totally sucks. I need that feature and command line fails for me :(